# I am getting an error creating a new key pair in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am getting an error when I try to **Create a New Key Pair** in AWS EC2. The specific error is: **"Error creating Key Pair: You are not authorized to perform this operation**."

I can confirm my account has the AmazonEC2FullAccess role. I cannot even Create a New Key Pair even before creating a new EC2 instance.

Can anyone provide insight as to this error and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you logged in as Admin ? or are you a different User ?

Comment: Please edit your question with the actual command that you are using and the type of key pair that you are trying to create.

Comment: What do you mean by "my account has the AmazonEC2FullAccess role"? Do you mean that the `AmazonEC2FullAccess` policy is attached to the IAM User that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have `ec2:CreateKeyPair` & `ec2:KeyPairName` permissions assigned for resource ARN `arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*`.